# Proof of non-emptiness of a set

Tags: real-analysis, infinity, supremum-and-infimum, convention

My goal is to prove that some set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^+$ (or $A \in \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{\infty\}$ if it is allowed to be written in this way) is nonempty.

*Unfortunately*, I cannot draw some element in $A$ because it is very difficult to know the nature of $A$.

*Fortunately*, suppose I know the infimum of $A$ cannot be infinite, that is,
$$\inf A < c \text{ for some constant $c < \infty$. }$$

Is this equivalent to state that "$A \neq \emptyset$"? I know the infimum of the emptyset is $\infty$ by convention, but I am not sure this convention can be used to prove non-emptiness.

Any clues or reference would be very appreciated.

***In addition***

I am also aware of the theorem stating that "every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded below has an infimum in $\mathbb{R}$". Is the converse of the theorem also true?

Comment: If inf A < $c$ then $c$ is not a lower bound of A. Therefore, there exists $x\in A$ with $x\le c$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, that is true. Can I then use this fact to state that $A \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: Yes. Notice that $x\in A$.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thank you! By the way, can we think this technique mathematically rigorous?I am asking this, because we are using the convention (not theorem) that infimum of empty set is $\infty$.

Comment: It simply uses the definition of the infimum of a set. It's perfectly rigorous.